# Field of blocking during editing. (Swift - iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitextfield

**Requirement**

I want to block a text field (UITextField) while another text  is being entered in another text field.

**Example**

I have two text fields on a form. When typing in the first text field, the second text field is disabled (i.e. you can not even press it by touching), only when you finish editing the first text field, you can edit the second one.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your textfield to an an array and use the `Equatable` protocol to compare the textfield in the `DidBeginEditing` func and "disable" other fields. But when you are done editing you need to turn all your textfields back on. Also make sure your class has `UITextFieldDelegate` in the declaration.

```
var textfields: [UITextField] = [textfield1,textfield2,textfieldn]

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    for field in textfields {
        if textField != field {
            field.enabled = false
        }
    }
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    for field in textfields {
        field.enabled = true
    }
}
```